# Spring-scheduling, scheduler run only first day 11:57PM not Everyday in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-scheduled

In my mvc project here i want to reapeate a Scheduler Everyday, But it working only First day when started device not Every day when device start permanently.

if i restart my device then it also working but only once again.

where Scheduler Class is,

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class Sched {

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 57 23 * * ?", zone="Asia/Kolkata")
    public void schedulerCreateFolder(){
        System.out.println("Hello Scheduller");
    }
}
```

And web app initializer is below,

```
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses(){
        return new Class[]{WebSecurityConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses(){
        return new Class[]{WebAppConfig.class, HibernateConfiguration.class, Sched.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings(){
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: do you have other method that annotate with **@Scheduled**?

Comment: yes i have 3 methods that annotated **@Scheduler** but all have same problem. Thanks to replying

Comment: spring @Scheduler only have one thread to execute your task, so i suggest you should print all the execution time for your scheduler method, i think you may have some task hung

Comment: I have 3 task at 3 different time period first is `0 57 23 ? * *` 2nd is `0 0 0 ? * *` and 3rd is `0 0 1 ? * *` . how can i handle it?

Comment: you can test with remove other two schedule first

Comment: Ok wait i will try it?

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for run a scheduler at 11:57pm every day, and you need to remove `zone`

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 57 23 * * ?")
```

Please check this link and you can validate your @Scheduled Syntax
https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html

Comment: @Alien He need to remove `zone` attribute

Comment: then mention in your answer.